# Is a Class 2 medical enough for being a (remunerated) Flight Instructor (FI (A)) in the European Union (EASA)?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical, eu

Suppose I *only* hold a valid PPL(A) License with a valid Class 2 medical certificate issued in the EU. Can I become a Flight Instructor for PPL(A) with this medical certificate or do I need to hold a Class 1 medical certificate?

As far as I understand it **I do not need a Class 1 medical certificate**, but please correct me if I am wrong.

From the EASA document below, you may either hold a CPL license hold at least a PPL(A) and have passed the CPL theoretical knowledge exam. Now, the CPL does require a Class 1 Medical certificate, but what about passing the CPL theoretical knowledge exam?

I am asking since, theoretically, with a PPL(A) you are not allowed to be paid for flying. Would then be being an instructor the only exception?

[This document](https://hub.easa.europa.eu/crt/docs/viewcrdattachment/cid_111883/aid_2561/fmd_b22a223e713b8adc5756567b36e0a1fd) states the following requirements: (See *SECTION 2: Specific requirements for the flight instructor — FI*):

> An applicant for an FI certificate shall:
>
> (a) have passed a specific
> pre-entry flight test with an FI qualified in accordance with  FCL.905.FI(j) within the 6 months preceding the start of the course,to assess their ability to undertake the course. This pre-entry flight test shall be based on the proficiency check for class and type ratings as set out in Appendix 9 to this Part;
>
> (b) for FI(A) and FI(H):
>
> 1. have received at least 10 hours of instrument flight
>    instruction on the appropriate aircraft category, of which not more
>    than 5 hours may be instrument ground time in an FSTD;
> 2. have completed 20 hours of VFR cross-country flight on the appropriate aircraft category as PIC; and
>
> (c) additionally, for the FI(A):
>
> 1. hold at least a CPL(A); or
> 2. hold at least a PPL(A) and have:
>    (i) passed the CPL theoretical knowledge exam, except for an FI(A) providing training for the LAPL(A) only; and
>    (ii) completed at least 200 hours of flight time on aeroplanes or TMGs, of which at least 150 hours shall be completed as PIC;
> 3. have completed at least 30 hours on single-engine piston powered aeroplanes of which at least 5 hours
>    shall have been completed during the 6 months preceding the pre-entry flight test set out in (a) above;
> 4. have completed a VFR cross-country flight as PIC, including a flight of at least 540 km (300 NM) in the course of which full stop landings at 2 different aerodromes shall be made.

Comment: I feel your pain, why do they make this so hard to understand?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can become a PPL(A) FI (without a CPL) with only a class 2 medical.

I did this, and I am the Chief Flying Instructor at an EASA ATO. We have employees who also do this.

> FCL.205.A PPL(A) — Privileges
>
> (a) The privileges of the holder of a PPL(A) are to act without
> remuneration as PIC or co-pilot on aeroplanes or TMGs engaged in
> non-commercial operations.
> (b) Notwithstanding the paragraph above,
> the holder of a PPL(A) with instructor or examiner privileges may
> receive remuneration for: (1) the provision of flight instruction for
> the LAPL(A) or PPL(A); So a PPL holder may give instruction.

> FCL.040 Exercise of the privileges of licences  The exercise of the
> privileges granted by a licence shall be dependent upon the validity
> of the ratings contained therein, if applicable, and of the medical
> certificate as appropriate to the privileges exercised. To Exercise
> the privileges of a PPL you need a Class 2 Medical Certificate.